# Проблема при установке LaTex

Tags: latex

Не могу установить TeX Live. Скачал инсталяху с сайта: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

`install-tl-windows.exe` (у меня Windows 7) и когда начинаю устанавливать идет распаковка в C:\TEMP\, но потом выдает ошибку:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы texlive встал на мою машину?

Comment: Возможно, архив битый. Там есть альтернатива, попробуйте ее: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip

Comment: NSIS бы ругнулся на битый инсталлер.

Answer (score 1):

в диалоге написано: распакуйте инсталлятор и, для получения более подробных сведений, запустите `install-tl-windows.bat` или `install-tl-advanced.bat`.

тогда, надо понимать, можно будет получить больше информации по поводу возникающей ошибки.